# Searching for an Program that controls other Programs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, build-automation, compilation

I'm using ubuntu (and WindowsXP as Virtual mashine on it).
I need an automatic process: I want my computer to do every hour a SVN Update and after that my Visual Studio 2008 should open the Projekt.sln File and run the Compilation Process (It's a Windows Program I want to compile, that's why I have to use Windows). For the Compilation Process I also need to make some adjustments (I want to compile it at first for 32bit and after that for 64bit Operation Systems - so I have to do two different compilations). After the Compilation I wanted to upload the Program...

Is there any chance I can do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a build server. There are a number of implementations out there, e.g. **[CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

[Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

[CruiseControl.Net](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)